# How to return a Firestore field value instead of a document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

All of the Firestore data retrieval examples show a full document getting returned.  Examples like this:

```
// Create a reference to the cities collection
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

// Create a query against the collection.
Query query = citiesRef.whereEqualTo("state", "CA");
```

My database has 3,000 city objects in it, and I need to get a list of all the unique states in my database.  Can someone show me an example of how I can get this information from Firestore?  I'm hoping I don't need to download all 3000 documents just to collate this list myself.

Comment: Cloud Firestore SDKs always return full documents. The only way to retrieve a subset of each document is through the REST API.

Comment: If you have a collection of cities, what you're going to get back is a number of cities. There are no built-in operators to transform a list of cities into a list of (unique) states. If you want a list of unique states, you'll want to store a collection of states (in addition to the cities you already have). This type of duplication is quite common in NoSQL databases. For a good introduction, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I really do appreciate your amazing Firebase support here on Stack Overflow, it really does make learning Firebase a LOT easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Cloud Function which is triggered by an `onWrite` event to your `cities` collection.  This function could see if the `state` already exists in a `states` collection and, if not, add it.

This way, you'll end up with a `states` collection which only has one of each `state` in it.  As states are generally a 2 letter code, you could use this code as the document index, to ensure uniqueness in your cloud function writes.

Answer (score 1):

As Frank says, the only way in which you can achieve this is by duplicationg data. This tehnique is named denormalization and for that I'll share you another resourse, which is a tutorial that I personally recomend you to see for a better understanding, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). This tutorial was made for Firebase Realtime database but the same principles are also in Cloud Firestore.

So to solve your problem, you need to create another top level collection in which you need to store only the unique states. But you need to be aware of the fact that every time you add or delete a document, you need to do it twice, once for the `cities` collection that you already have and second for the newly created collection `uniqueStates`.